# Facebook JS API: users_getInfo() inside ifUserConnected() deadlock

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to put Facebook connect button on the site and once connected display connected username. But for some reason following code goes into some infinite loop during first connection, and then works fine unless I delete this app from my facebook profile which causes freezing again.

Here is a code on FB connect button click:

```
FB.Connect.requireSession();
```

Here is code directly on the page:

```
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php/en_US" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB.init("123", "/xd_receiver.htm");
    FB.ensureInit(function() {
        FB.Connect.ifUserConnected(function() {
            FB.Facebook.apiClient.users_getInfo(new Array(FB.Connect.get_loggedInUser()),new Array("name"), function(user, exec) {
            console.log("logged in:"+user[0].name);
            });

        }, function(){
            console.log("guest");
        });
    });
</script>
```

If I remove `FB.Facebook.apiClient.users_getInfo()` it works fine, but I need to get username somehow. Any tips?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to pass username parameter as array like:

```
FB.Facebook.apiClient.users_getInfo(new Array(FB.Connect.get_loggedInUser()),new Array("name","username"), function(user, exec) {
            console.log("logged in:"+user[0].name);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get like this;

```
FB.Facebook.apiClient.users_getInfo(loggedInUsersId, ['first_name','last_name','email','sex','birthday','username'], function(result,ex){
       alert(result[0]['username']);
    });
```